# Knowledge Based System of a family tree in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have these family facts:

```
male(jerry).
male(stuart).
male(warren).
male(peter).
female(kather).
female(maryalice).
female(ann).
brother(jerry,stuart).
brother(jerry,kather).
brother(peter, warren).
sister(ann, maryalice).
sister(kather,jerry).
parent_of(warren,jerry).
parent_of(maryalice,jerry).
```

And using the base predicates `male`, `female` and `parent_of` I want to define `father`, `mother`, `son`, `daughter`, `sibling`, `spouse` and `parent_of`.

This is what I have done:

```
father(P,C) :- male(P), parent_of(P,C).
mother(P,C) :- female(P), parent_of(P,C).
son(C,P) :- male(C), parent_of(P,C).
daughter(C,P) :- female(C), parent_of(P,C).
sibling(C,OC) :- parent_of(P,C), parent_of(P,OC).
spouse(H,W) :- parent_of(H,C), parent_of(W,C).
parent_of(P,C) :-
    ( ( sister(C,OC) ; sister(OC,C))
    ; ( brother(C,OC) ; brother(OC,C))).
```

By querying `parent_of(P,C)` it should return that `warren` is a parent of `jerry,stuart and kather` and that `maryalice` is a parent of `jerry, stuart and kather` also. But this is what I get:

```
?- parent_of(X,Y).
X = warren,
Y = jerry ;
X = maryalice,
Y = jerry ;
Y = ann ;
Y = kather ;
Y = maryalice ;
Y = jerry ;
Y = jerry ;
Y = jerry ;
Y = peter ;
Y = stuart ;
Y = kather ;
Y = warren.
```

It does not make any sense! Any help is much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up facts and predicates which is basically possible but not a recommended approach (at least in this case).

You wrote that you want to define `male`, `female` and `parent_of` as basic facts but in your first source code above you define also `sister` and `brother`. That you can easily define by a rule like "S is a sister of X when S is female and has a parent C and X has the same parent C and is not equal to S".
There is no need for re-defining `parent_of` by `sister` and `brother`.

Now let's have a look at the result of your query:

The first two results are the facts you defined (warren and jerry, marryalice and jerry).

The next results are produced by your predicate. Since you did not specify anything about the variable `P` it remains unbound and is not printed in the result (thus only `Y = ...` is shown).

And the variable `C` in the predicate fulfills one of the four conditions you specified (`C` is a sister of somebody (ann, kather), somebody is a sister of `C` (maryalice,jerry), `C` is a brother of somebody (two times jerry, peter) or somebody is a brother of `C` (stuart, kather, warren).

**Summary**: Replace the definitions of `brother` and `sister` by rules and drop the `parent_of` predicate.

Comment: Thank you for you reply @danielp and @CapelliC. I made these two rules: `sister(S,X) :- female(S), parent_of(C,S), parent_of(C,X), S \= X.` and `brother(S,X) :- male(S), parent_of(C,S), parent_of(C,X), S \= X.`, and removed the `parent_of` rule. I have tried quering `parent_of(X,Y).` both with the brother and sister facts and without them, but it still only returns the facts I defined (warren and jerry, maryalice and jerry).

Comment: What additional results beside those you defined do you expect?

Comment: Because `jerry` has siblings `stuart` and `kather` I also except to see that `warren` is a parent of `stuart` and `kather`. Also that `maryalice` is parent of `stuart` and `kather`.

Comment: Decide whether you want to infer (i.e. have a rule for) parentship by looking at the siblings or vice-versa. If you drop the brother/sister facts, you have to add e.g. `parent_of(maryalica,stuart)` as a fact.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the answer by danielp, but I hope to attract your attention on another problem, that maybe has gone unnoticed: why X appears only on the first two results ? That's because your last predicate  is effectively

```
parent_of(P,C) :- sister(C,OC).
parent_of(P,C) :- sister(OC,C).
parent_of(P,C) :- brother(C,OC).
parent_of(P,C) :- brother(OC,C).
```

and P is never bound by such rules. So, you're right

> It does not make any sense!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to Prolog, what do you mean with "P is never bound to such rules?" Does it have something to with P only being on the left side of the rule? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, P is a so called *singleton*. As such, pretty useless, and since it doesn't get a value it's not shown by the Prolog toplevel (user interface, so called REPL, ReadEvalPrintLoop).

Comment: Thank you, think I get it now. Please see my comment below: Do you know why the parent_of-query only returns the two parent_of-facts I defined and not anything more?